# Удалить элемент коллекции типа SplineBezierPoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

Есть коллекция специального типа [SplineBezierPoints](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.SplineBezierPoints.html).

Известен порядковый номер элемента, который нужно удалить из коллекции. Но [описании типа](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.SplineBezierPoints.html) есть только функция добавить, но не удалить. Каким образом можно удалять элементы из таких коллекций?

**UPD:** 
Вариант с `del` не прокатывает:

```
>>> del C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: del bpy_prop_collection[key]: not supported
```

Remove() нету:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2:** Вариант с присвоением тоже не прокатывает:

```
>>> C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1:]
[bpy.data.curves['BezierCircle'].splines[0].bezier_points[1], bpy.data.curves['BezierCircle'].splines[0].bezier_points[2], bpy.data.curves['BezierCircle'].splines[0].bezier_points[3]]

>>> C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points=C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "bezier_points" from "Spline" is read-only
```

Comment: К элементу коллекции можно обращаться через индекс? `coll[i]` ? Если да, то просто `del coll[i]`

Comment: @ReinRaus Обращаться можно, а вот удалить так не получается

Comment: А так пробовали: `C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points = C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1:]` - в общем идея в том, чтобы вернуть список со всеми элементами кроме удаляемого и перезаписать изначальную переменную...

Comment: @MaxU нет, не выходит, пишет, что `attribute "bezier_points" from "Spline" is read-only`

Comment: Не пойму. В документации не написано как объект удалить?

Comment: @МистерФикс стал бы я спрашивать, если-бы нашел это в доках?

Comment: Ну раз в доках нет, то может и нет, тогда возможности удаления. Дело в том, что некоторые массивы, например строковые, или кортежи, не поддерживают методов удаления своего наполнения. Их всегда надо пересобирать заново. Это цена за то, что они работают быстрее чем списки.

Comment: @МистерФикс, так или иначе удалить объект этот можно, для этого его надо выделить и выполнить функцию, которая удаляет выделение. Но я не хочу ее использовать, тк теряю выделение.

Comment: Никогда блендером не пользовался, поэтому не понимаю, что значит "выделение".

Comment: @Crantisz, ну так посмотрите в исходниках как это делает функция для выделенного объекта... Что возвращают методы: `C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points.data`  и `C.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points.values()`?

Comment: @MaxU `del bpy.data.curves['BezierCircle'].splines[0].bezier_points.values()[2]` никак не влияет, хотя ошибок не выводит.

Comment: @MaxU _ну так посмотрите в исходниках как это делает функция для выделенного объекта..._ не знаю где смотреть, есть подозрение, что функция написана на C, а мне все-таки нужен python

Comment: @Crantisz, я бы вместо того чтобы удалять, скорее пытался отфильтровать, оставляя только нужные элементы

Comment: а что говорит DocString: `p = bpy.data.curves['BezierCircle'].splines[0].bezier_points; p.update?`

Comment: `>>> p = bpy.data.curves['BezierCircle'].splines[0].bezier_points; p.update
<built-in method update of bpy_prop_collection object at 0x7f3beaf633f0>`

Comment: @Crantisz, я имел в виду среду iPython (Interactive Python) - если в `ipython` ввести `p.update?` (со знаком вопроса, можно еще попробовать с двумя), то он должен показать DocString для метода `update()`

Comment: MaxU, это не iPython, а встроеная консоль в Blender. Если Вам интересно, может быть лучше попробовать самому, чем использовать меня как испорченный телефон? на `p.update?` пишет `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку удалить элемент коллекции не получается, единственный выход, что я нашел - использовать оператор для этого. Это не очень хорошо, поскольку приходится выделять точки, которые нужно удалить.

1. Выделяем точки

   ```
   bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')

   for dot in dellist:
       dot.select_control_point=True
   ```
2. Удаляем

   ```
   bpy.ops.curve.delete(type='VERT')
   ```

Некрасиво, но работает...

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления можно использовать конструкцию `del` - как для коллекций, массивов, так и для переменных и свойств.

```
list = [1,2,3]
del list[0]
// [2,3]
```

Мы также можем отчистить всю коллекцию, массив.

```
del list[:]
// []
```

Также у коллекций есть функция `.remove(значение)` - которая удаляет первое найденное значение из списка.

```
list = [1,2,1,2,1]
list.remove(list[1])
//[1,1,2,1]
```

Comment: Не прокатывает. Дописал в вопросе текст ошибки